# bash script meant to start automatically when booting runs twice

Tags: raspbian, boot

I have this script meant to run when booting (named bootMF):

```
!/bin/bash
cd /media/pi/2E2D-29D01
sleep 120
python3 telnetRX006RBN.py &
sleep 10
python3 telnetRX006DXK.py &
sleep 70
python3 analyse039.py &
sleep 60
python3 WatchDog002.py &
exit
```

I inserted this line in .profile:

```
(sleep 15 && /home/pi/bootMF) &
```

Now when I reboot with 'shutdown -r now' all python scripts are started twice as you can see here:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -ef | grep python
pi        1470     1  0 15:41 ?        00:00:02 python3 telnetRX006RBN.py
pi        1472     1  0 15:41 tty1     00:00:01 python3 telnetRX006RBN.py
pi        1474     1  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 python3 telnetRX006DXK.py
pi        1476     1  0 15:42 tty1     00:00:00 python3 telnetRX006DXK.py
pi        1478     1 14 15:43 ?        00:01:20 python3 analyse039.py
pi        1480     1 14 15:43 tty1     00:01:21 python3 analyse039.py
pi        1496     1  0 15:44 ?        00:00:00 python3 WatchDog002.py
pi        1497     1  0 15:44 tty1     00:00:00 python3 WatchDog002.py
pi        1594  1446  0 15:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

Can anyone tell me why they are started twice? When I run bootMF manually using 'bash bootMF' they only start once.

Comment: `.profile` is a (no offense) dumb place to start one-off services as it is *not* something which is guaranteed to be loaded only once.   See `INVOCATION` under `man bash`.

Comment: no offense taken :-), complete newbie on linux here. Thanks for your input.

Comment: removed the command from `.profile` and added it to `rc.local`. Seems to work better now.

Comment: @ON5MF Could you add this as an answer, so that people know the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the comments `.profile` is not a good place to put a script that needs to start when booting Raspbian.

So now I put it in `rc.local` and it works a lot better.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.